# Python how compare contents of two CSV files with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file with 60 different server names, but how do I save all the server names to a list and make a loop that checks if every servername is in the list? Lets say tommorow I compare with a similar CSV file, but it only contains 50 server names. I want it to spit out the servers missing in a print operation how can I do that?

Here is my current code - It reads the CSV file and prints all the server names with an index from 0-59.

```
csv_file = 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\csvfolder/some_file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, delimiter=';', skiprows=0, low_memory=False)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to use python [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

See below:

```
yesterday_servers = {'s1','s3','s8'}
today_servers = {'s1','s8','s19'}

new_servers = today_servers - yesterday_servers
missing_servers  = yesterday_servers - today_servers
print(f' missing {missing_servers}')
print(f' new {new_servers}')
```

output

```
 missing {'s3'}
 new {'s19'}
```

Comment: Oh that's great thanks I'll manually add `yesterday_servers` list with all the 60 server names, but how do I automatically add the servers to  `today_servers` from the pandas csv reader? @balderman

Comment: @Farzadmirzaii Why do you need pandas here?

Comment: I download a new csv each day and I want it to compare the servers each day to make print an error if a server suddenly is missing - that's why I need pandas to compare every day with a new downloaded csv file to make sure all 60 servers is still there.

Comment: The code that I have posted will do the "diff" for you - no need for pandas.

Comment: `today_servers` does not take servernames from the csv file so